# Ribbon Custom action for creating new page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, ribbon, custom-actions

I would like to create a new Ribbon Custom action for creating new page, because I want to have more control on creating new page. I have created a SharePoint hosted app and added new ribbon custom action item. I chose List Template for scope and for particular item I chose Pages Library and for for control located I chose Ribbon.ListItem.Manage. but it is not visible. is it possible to make a Ribbon Action visible always where ever you are? thanks.